# How to fetch WooCommerce data from a Rest API efficiently?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, pagination, woocommerce-rest-api

From an Angular web application I try to fetch data from a WooCommerce Subscriptions Rest API endpoint. WooCommerce limits the data to 100 items per page. So I have to create a pagination system.

What I created works in general. But I think that the solution is not really efficient. What do you think about?

**My try**

```
page: number = 1;

_fetchAPI(currentUserEmail, currentUserUid) {
    let apiURL = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions?per_page=100&page=' + this.page;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('exampletoken')
    });

    const myObject: any = {
      // Params
    };
    const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: myObject } as HttpParamsOptions;

    const options = { params: new HttpParams(httpParams), headers: headers };

    return this.http.get<any>(apiURL, options)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {

        // Return if the current page has no results -> End of pages
        if (!data.length) {
          return;
        }

        for(let value of data) {
          if (value.billing.email == currentUserEmail) {
            if (value.status == 'active' || value.status == 'pending-cancel') {
              this.db.makePRO(currentUserUid);
              break;
            } 
          } 
        }

        // Fetch next Page
        this.page += 1;
        this._fetchAPI(currentUserEmail, currentUserUid);

    });
}
```

Is this way okay? Or is there a more elegant way to handle such things? In general I just want to know if a subscription exists for a specific email address. Would be much easier to have a method to get subscriptions by email. But there is only a 'get subscriptions by id' endpoint. So I have to load all data to compare just one email address....

Maybe you have an idea? I would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Is there a way to get `id` by email? Then you could call `get subscriptions by id`

Comment: I don't think so. Here is the documentation and there I can't find nothing about it: https://woocommerce.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/?javascript#retrieve-a-subscription